# ASP.NET MVC 4 Route for Bookmarked Angular SPA URLs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to build a single-page application in AngularJS with client-side routing done in HTML5 mode.  In case users ever bookmark a page on my site, I understand that I need a basic server-side routing scheme but I really want it to just always serve up my single homepage and propagate the same URL to the client-side routing piece.

This catch-all route works perfectly on simple URLs that are only one deep:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{*catchall}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Example URLs:

```
http://myapp.com/moreInfo
http://myapp.com/contactUs
```

"moreInfo" and "contactUs" are just named routes within Angular.  The only real entry point to the single-page application is at http://myapp.com.  So far, this all works very smoothly.

When I try to go more than one route deep, though, the application goes into an infinite loop:

```
http://myapp.com/user/5
```

Is this because my server-side route is not sufficient to "pass along" the "user/5" URL to my client application?  Do I need to do anything special to make sure that no matter how deeply nested the URL is, it gets passed along to my SPA properly?

Answer (score 10):

The problem is not with the routing configuration, I have a similar setup with angular js and mvc 4, and the route below works fine.

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Application",
  url: "{*url}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
  namespaces: new[] { "MyApp.Web.Controllers" });
```

Do you have the html5Mode set to true in the angular config method?

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

You might try to send a get request to your app with fiddler and look at the response. If it is a 301 or 302, then you have a server side redirection loop issue. If it is 200, then your angular/js code might be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the'/user/5' to be given to the routing engine in Angular.  If this is the case, Angular deals with the route after the hash.  This means the route you want is

```
http://myapp.com#/user/5
```

You will also need to configure the $routeProvider properly with a route like:

```
angular.module('yourApp', []).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
      when('/user/:id', {templateUrl: 'SOME_HTML_FILE'}).
      otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);
```

You would then need to get the route param out in the controller:

```
function someController($scope, $routeParams) {
  if($routeParams.id){
       alert('Super Fly!');
  }
}
```